# `startTransition` does not prevent suspense with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client, react-suspense

I have a `react-native` (v0.72.4) app built with `expo` (v49.0.0) that does not seem to be respecting the use of `startTransition` within a suspense component.

(irrelevant code has been trimmed from the snippet)

```
function Container({
  navigation,
}: ContainerProps): JSX.Element {
  const { ctx } = useTopTabContext();
  const { address } = ctx;
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const { client, data, fetchMore } = useSuspenseQuery(
    QUERY,
    {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
      variables: {
        address,
        filters: {
          limit: 100,
        },
      },
    }
  );

  const loadMore = () => {
    if (data?.wallet?.items?.pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
      const nextPage = page + 1;
      startTransition(() => {
        fetchMore({
          variables: {
            filters: {
              limit: 100,
              page: nextPage,
            },
          },
        }).then(() => {
          setPage(nextPage);
        });
      });
    }
  };

  const rows = useMemo(() => {
    const nodes = data?.wallet?.items?.edges?.map((e) => e.node) ?? [];
    return convertDataToFlatlist(nodes);
  }, [data?.wallet?.items?.edges]);

  return (
    <View f={1} mt={16} px={-5}>
      <FlashList
        estimatedItemSize={197}
        data={rows}
        numColumns={2}
        onEndReached={loadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The call to the `@apollo/client` function for `fetchMore` that is returned from the hook is clearly wrapped in the `startTransition` function which *should* be preventing the component from going back into the fallback loading state (and *does* work completely fine when built and compiled for web using regular `react`), but regardless of the transition, the component always falls back to it's loading state when the `loadMore` function is executed.

Has anyone else experienced this type of issue with suspense with react native, or found a solution?